# ¿Cual es la forma adecuada de gestionar multiples posibilidades?

Tags: c++, c++11

Cada posibilidad tiene una respuesta. Se que habría que hacerlo con `switch`/`case`, pero tengo entendido que solo funciona con constantes, y lo que yo uso es una variable, ¿no? He intentado usarlo y me daba errores de sintaxis.

Lo que yo he hecho me parece una chapuza.

Explico lo que se supone que hace: al invocar la función le paso un 1 o un 0. Si le paso un 1, estoy en el ámbito de las respuestas positivas y si le paso otra cosa (en este caso un 0), en el de las negativas. Luego dentro de cada ámbito genera un numero aleatorio que va de 1 a 4, y dependiendo del número que salga debe emitir una respuesta.

```
void respramdom(int x1)
{
    if (x1 == 1)
    {
        int numaleatorio = randomInt2(engine);

        if (numaleatorio == 1)
            cout << "Very good!\n";
        else if(numaleatorio == 2)
            cout << "Excellent\n";
        else if(numaleatorio == 3)
            cout << "Nice work!\n";
        else
            cout << "Keep up the good work!\n";
    }

    else
    {
        int numaleatorio = randomInt2(engine);

        if (numaleatorio == 1)
            cout << "No. Please try again.\n";
        else if (numaleatorio == 2)
            cout << "Wrong. Try once more.\n";
        else if (numaleatorio == 3)
            cout << "Don't give up!\n";
        else
            cout << "No. Keep trying.\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Debería que hacerlo con `switch`/`case`, pero tengo entendido que sólo funciona con constantes.

El `switch` funciona con constantes y variables, el `case` requiere constantes. Por lo tanto tu código podría quedar así:

```
void respramdom(int x1)
{
    if (x1 == 1)
    {
        switch (randomInt2(engine))
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Very good!\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Excellent\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Nice work!\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Keep up the good work!\n";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (randomInt2(engine))
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "No. Please try again.\n";
            case 2:
                cout << "Wrong. Try once more.\n";
            case 3:
                cout << "Don't give up!\n";
            default:
                cout << "No. Keep trying.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Pero ni siquiera necesitas un `switch` para esta tarea:

```
void respramdom(int x1)
{
    static const std::string respuestas[4][2]
    {
        {"Keep up the good work!", "No. Keep trying."},
        {"Very good!",             "No. Please try again."},
        {"Excellent",              "Wrong. Try once more."},
        {"Nice work!",             "Don't give up!"},
    };

    int numaleatorio = randomInt2(engine);
    numaleatorio = ((numaleatorio > 0) && (numaleatorio < 4)) ? numaleatorio : 0;
    x1 = x1 == 1 ? 0 : 1;

    std::cout << respuestas[numaleatorio][x1] << '\n';
}
```